# File Association Dilemma in Vista

Tags: windows-vista, microsoft-office, file-association

I have both Office 2003 and Office 2007 installed on my laptop. I need Office 2007 occasionally for work-related issues but for all other purposes I use Office 2003. But now when I double-click on a .doc or .xls file it gets opened with the corresponding Office 2007 application. I set up file associations for .doc and .xls files that specifically point to the Office 2003 applications but Vista ignores my instructions and forces me to use Office 2007. This has had a catastrophic effect upon my work flow apart from being an utterly ridiculous situation. Is there any way to override this intrusion of Office 2007 short of uninstalling the program?

Comment: What? You mean you'd rather use an older version of office than 2007?!

Comment: I can't recall, does Office 2007 have an entry on Control Panel\Programs\Default Programs\Set Default Programs?

Answer (score 1):

i posted this elsewhere yesterday, maybe this will help.

the dilemma: Vista doesn't allow you to choose anything but the default programs, such as the programs listed in your files' context menus. If you want complete control over your file types, follow these steps:

1. Download and install [Creative Element Power Tools](http://www.creativelement.com/powertools/).
2. Open the Creative Element Power Tools Control Panel.
3. Turn on the Edit file type associations option, and click Accept.
4. Right-click a file of the type you want to change, and select Edit File Type to show this window:

[image]

[Source](http://www.annoyances.org/exec/show/article02-500)

Answer (score 1):

You can follow some of the answers given here: 
[Associate a File Type with a Specific Program](https://superuser.com/questions/29717/associate-a-file-type-with-a-specific-program)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://nicolask.wordpress.com/2008/10/19/set-the-default-program-word-2003-or-word-2007-to-open-doc-documents/) it seems you can restore file associations by going to `Help` -> `Detect and Repair` in Office 2003.