# Change file icon but keep same app

Tags: windows, windows-8, file-association

It there a way to apply a different icon to my .php .js and .css files and yet open them with the same app (Sublime Text or Notepad++).

I tried using [FileTypesMan](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) in no avail.

It changes the icon of the app and thus all other file types that are assoc. with this app.

I just want to apply icons like these and open them with the same app:
[image]

Comment: Possible answer here: http://superuser.com/questions/158012/associate-icon-with-file-of-specific-type

Comment: @NathanC Yep, that should do it.

Comment: Yep, I knew about the RegEdit solution. I just needed something more user friendly with UI. Thanks.

Comment: @miro: I don't understand why FileTypesMan didn't help. When you edited the .JS or .CSS file type and [specified the icon](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wdvP6.png), what exactly did you select as the Default Icon?

Comment: All file types that use the same app get the same icon.  So when I change the .css icon, the .js and .php icons also changes to the same icon because they are all handled by Notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

There's no Windows-native way of doing that. Your options are: either to manually edit registry or use 3rd-party tools such as [Types](http://izt.name/apps/types/) to make these changes.

Comment: Nope. It does exactly the same thing as change icon trough windows. Both .js and .css get the same icon because they are handled by the same app.

Comment: @miro are you associating files or changing their associated icons?

Comment: Trying to change their associated icon. But when I change the icon for .js it also changes the icon for .css