# how to force any *.sdf file to open with My program?

Tags: windows-registry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Associate a File Type with a Specific Program](https://superuser.com/questions/29717/associate-a-file-type-with-a-specific-program)

how to force any `*.sdf` file to open with My program?

for example: every `*.sdf` file will open with this program: `D:\MyProg.exe`

**I need any registry value for this**.

how to do it?

Comment: Have you tried making MyProg.exe the default application for a .sdf file ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the needed registry entries. you can save it as a .reg file (for example sdef_associate.reg) and use the command line tool reg (build in windows) to import it
for example:
REG IMPORT sdef_associate.reg

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.sdf]
@="sdef_file"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sdef_file]
@=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sdef_file\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sdef_file\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sdef_file\shell\open\command]
@="\"D:\\myprog.exe\" %1"
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but it not work. the *.sdf in my computer Always open with visual-studio 2008