# How to associate a file with a program in Windows via CMD

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, file-association

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Associate a File Type with a Specific Program](https://superuser.com/questions/29717/associate-a-file-type-with-a-specific-program)

How do I change file association via the cmd.exe prompt?

I know this is similar to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/29717/associate-a-file-type-with-a-specific-program) question, but I'm only concerned with CMD.

Comment: Do similar questions where an answer isn't picked, qualify as an exact duplicate question?

Comment: Yes, an answer doesn't have to be accepted by the OP for the question to be the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm editing my answer, because you *can* do it.  The FTYPE command, in conjunction with the ASSOC command will let you change file associations.

To find your file type associations, you use the assoc command at the command prompt. Make sure you pipe it to the more filter because the list is quite long and will scroll out of your buffer.

```
assoc | more
```

After you know how you want to change the file associations, use the ftype command:

```
ftype TIFImage.Document="C:\Program Files\MSPVIEW.exe" "%1"
```