# change the default program for a file extension

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Associate a File Type with a Specific Program](https://superuser.com/questions/29717/associate-a-file-type-with-a-specific-program)

I downloaded a program and it configures itself as default program for `.mdf` files and I see a ugly icon for mdf files in my windows right now!

As default, mdf files has a nice icon on it and there was no program associated with this file type.

Given that there was no program associated with that, I cannot get back the settings. Is there any way I can reverse this inside registry or something?

Comment: @techie007 it is not the same. I remove all the associated programs for this file. It is not possible to do this with UI.

Comment: There are more than one answer provided, did none of them suffice?  Are you looking to associate a "Default Program", as in your title, or just an icon?

Answer (score 0):

first place to try and mess with it is
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\  (and the extention itself of course)

Now you could do a quick export of that section, just for backup purposes. Right click Export, or in the menu File Export, Selected branch. . .
Then delete away :-)   Removing UserChoice will probably get rid of the re-iconification.