# How to export and import all file extensions is being associated with a specific program?

Tags: windows, windows-7, file-association, export, import

I've associated some types of files to open with some specific programs. Now, I want to export all the associated data above and to import those to another computer.

For example: I want to export all associated file types open with Notepad++.exe, and then import that data to another computer.

I consulted this answer: [Associate a File Type with a Specific Program](https://superuser.com/a/29719/946334)

However, all methods are simply to view, cannot export those data (nor can it be imported). With the #3 method (using "File Type Doctor") seems to be able to export data but I cannot know whether it can import data or not because the tool has stopped being supported, can't download it down, install and use.

I also tried with the "FileTypesMan" tool but quite similar to method #2, it cannot export / import data.

So I needed a method that would help me export all associated file types open with a specific program, and be able to import those data to another computer (quite similar to configuration data).

UPDATE: The method needs to be able to work on older versions of windows (minimum Windows 7).

I will appreciate your method.

Answer (score 1):

This answer only applies to Windows 10 and Windows 11.

> So I needed a method that would help me export all associated file types open with a specific program and be able to import those data to another computer (quite similar to configuration data).

Run the following command in an elevated PowerShell prompt to export the file associations:

> `dism /online /Export-DefaultAppAssociations:"%UserProfile%\Desktop\FileAssociations.xml"`

Run the following command in an elevated PowerShell prompt to import the file association:

> `dism /online /Import-DefaultAppAssociations:"%UserProfile%\Desktop\FileAssociations.xml"`

To reverse the import, run the following command in an elevated PowerShell prompt:

> `Dism.exe /Online /Remove-DefaultAppAssociations`

Source:

- [How to Export and Import File Associations in Windows 10](https://winaero.com/how-to-export-and-import-file-associations-in-windows-10/amp/)
- [Generate a default app associations XML File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/export-or-import-default-application-associations?view=windows-11#generate-a-default-app-associations-xml-file)

Comment: Oh, this method only works on Windows 10 and above. And I am looking to move data from Windows 7 (to Windows 10) so it has no `get-defaultappassociations` option.

Comment: @TầnQuảng - Export the entire registry key for all file extensions. I took a lot of time to research this answer. I am going to leave it as is.